# UITableViewCell image from web

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage, afnetworking

I'm going to download `images` and `titles` from web (probably using `AFNetworking`) and insert inside `UITableViewCell`. Since `images` are not same size I'll need to calculate size for every cell.

Currently in my `Post` model I have `title` and `imageURL`. Should I first download all images, insert in array and then add to cell or should I use that AFNetworking function inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and download images from there?

Since I'm going to need images in both `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `heightForRow` (for calculation), downloading all `images` first and storing in `array` might be better solution but dunno if cache is doing all the work so I could go with second approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually in short - should I prepare images inside model or download and adjust images inside cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: If possible for u change the server reponse, u send the image size also in your response. Then simply calculate the size of cell then using AsyncImageview or AFNetworking to load image in cell

Comment: I will have to do some image resizing also (its something like facebook timeline) so dunno if I can send size from server...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13105218/1405008 refer this if its helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fot the better performance,

> You should approach for the Small sizes of images or few.
>    downloading all images first and storing in array.

**IF the images are huge**, then should go for the Asynchronous task to display.

and then Use the custom `UIImageView` within the cell to show the image.