# How to change UITableViewCell height when download image finished?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I want to resize the `tableviewcell` when `SDWebImage` download finished.

Where should I put `[UITableViewCell setNeedsUpdateConstraints]`?
Or just send notification to `UIViewController` and reload tableview data?

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <Masonry/Masonry.h>
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

#define WEAKSELF typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;

@interface ViewController ()
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    UITableView *myTableView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *items;
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (UIRectEdge)edgesForExtendedLayout {
    return UIRectEdgeNone;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reloadRows:)
                                                 name:@"ReloadRows"
                                               object:nil];

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 30; i ++) {
        CGFloat width = arc4random() % 100 + 20.0f;
        CGFloat height = arc4random() % 100 + 20.0f;
        CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width, height);
        [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:size]];
    }
    self.items = array;

    myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    myTableView.dataSource = self;
    myTableView.delegate = self;
    myTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0f;
    myTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    [self.view addSubview:myTableView];

    UIView *superview = self.view;
    [myTableView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.right.top.bottom.equalTo(superview);
    }];
}
- (void)reloadRows:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSIndexPath *ip = notification.object;
    if (ip) {
        TestCell *cell = [myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];
        [cell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[ip] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}
#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.items count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellID = @"Contact_People_Cell";
    TestCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[TestCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }
    NSValue *value = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageSize = [value CGSizeValue];
    [cell refreshInterface];
    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
@end
```

**TestCell**

```
#define SIZE_DEFAULT CGSizeMake(140.0f, 100.0f)
@interface TestCell () {
    UIImageView *imv;
}
@end

@implementation TestCell
@synthesize imageSize;
@synthesize indexPath;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        [self setupView];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)setupView {
    imv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    imv.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:imv];

    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    UIView *superView = self.contentView;
    [imv mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.width.equalTo(@(SIZE_DEFAULT.width));
        make.height.equalTo(@(SIZE_DEFAULT.height));
        make.left.top.bottom.equalTo(superView).with.offset(10.0f);
    }];
}
- (void)updateConstraints {
    [super updateConstraints];
    UIView *superView = self.contentView;
    [imv mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.left.top.equalTo(superView).with.offset(10.0f);
        make.bottom.equalTo(superView).with.offset(-10.0f);
        make.width.equalTo(@(ceilf(self.imageSize.width)));
        make.height.equalTo(@(ceilf(self.imageSize.height)));
    }];
}
- (void)refreshInterface {
    WEAKSELF
    [imv sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.baidu.com"]
           placeholderImage:nil
                    options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload
                   progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {}
                  completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                      imv.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];

                      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                          CGFloat width = arc4random() % 100 + 140.0f;
                          CGFloat height = arc4random() % 100 + 140.0f;
                          CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width, height);
                          weakSelf.imageSize = size;

                          [weakSelf setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

//                          NSIndexPath *ip = [weakSelf.indexPath copy];
//                          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReloadRows" object:ip];
                      });
                  }];
}
@end
```

Comment: refer to this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13105218/4030971

Answer (score 0):

Use self-sized cells. After load image, change height constraint of `UIImage` and call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` method

Answer (score 0):

implement `tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method to change the cell height as per downloaded image height