# iOS Image size for downloading

Tags: ios, image, server

In my application I need to download an image from a server and display it in a tableView. However, the app is made for all devices and in both orientations(Landscape and portrait).

I have 2 problems now. First, I don't know what size I should download the image or if I should create an index of sizes and depending on the device that is being used, download the respective image. But the problem there is that the size of the image is different in both orientations so would I need to re download the image if the orientation is changed?

Second, I have a script on my server where I can pass the image and the size as a parameter in the URL, and it will resize the image on the server before downloading it. I'm not sure if this is a good idea since it could take a lot of processing time if many people use the app at the same time.

This is a question I have had for ages and after reading many articles and other questions I still don't understand. To be clear I do understand the difference between the @1x, @2x and @3x formats and i'm not asking about these.

If anything is unclear, please don't hesitate to ask and I'll add the respective information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain all the image handling for you.

First things first, the x1 x2 x3 are for images within the app itself. They are added in assets for images that are within the app (like icons, backgrounds, etc). When you download an image or get the image from the server, you shouldn't worry about x1 x2 and x3 at all since these images are data and not assets. So now that is aside.

Second of all, answering your original question, you have 3 ways of implementing what you need. Either let the back-end give you the size of each image and its url. Thus you preset the respective frame and then download the image. Another way is to make the tableView dynamic so when the image downloads it resizes the cell automatically. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13105218/3165112) should answer your question. One last solution is to use a property called content mode on the UIImage. More details about it are [here](http://jacksonkr.com/content/uiimageview-scaling-explained-visually)

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for your response. First of all, I think I miss understood the concept of 1x etc. thank you for clearing this up. Second I did know the use of the content mode and I am not trying to resize the tableview, what I am trying to understand is what size I should download the image, especially if the orientation is changed, should I download another image?

Comment: download the image in its original size if you want it all to display. For me it is better to handle the image from your side than to let the backed become slow to process them all. and when you rotate you device, the application will be oriented along with your images so you shouldn't worry about orientation if you use auto layout

Comment: That is a very nice idea, I will use this. However, is there a thumbs up rule on the size of the image. The original images are quite large and up to various MB, I know this is way too much, so do you know a good size I can shrink it to?

Comment: ah yes, if the resolution of the images are way too high (images from server are 4k for example) then you should definitly reduce them before sending them. You can achoieve that as you said by stating the resolution from the url of the image. I suggest to shrink each image to 0.5 mbs max to keeo theperformance of the phone great (memory management and loading to the ram)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping 2 different sized images of the same image file and loading them based on the orientation.

For example if you are using the app in portrait mode the image "image_portrait.jpg" will be loaded, else "image_landscape.jpg".

You can also keep different size images based on 2x and 3x devices since 1x is almost obsolete now.

So if someone is loading image on iphone 5 or 6 you could load "image_portrait_2x.jpg", for 6 plus or 7 plus "image_portrait_3x.jpg".

Also it would be good to use NSCache so that the images do not get downloaded every time the orientation changes or the tableview is scrolled.